# How do you adjust FreeTDS options through DBD::Sybase?

Tags: sql-server, perl, freebsd, dbi

I have a database hosted on SQL Server 2012 Standard on Windows 2012. Using FreeBSD 10 with p5-DBI-1.6.33 and p5-DBD-Sybase-1.15_1, I can connect to it and run toy queries using the following Perl code.

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "dbi:Sybase:server=mydb.example.com",
    "username",
    "mypassword",
    {"RaiseError" => 1, "PrintError" => 0},
);
print "Connected.\n";

my $version = $dbh->selectall_arrayref('SELECT @@VERSION', {Columns => {}});
print Dumper($version);

my $tables = $dbh->selectall_arrayref("SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables", {Columns => {}});
print Dumper($tables);
```

This works, however I need to replace /usr/local/etc/freetds/freetds.conf with the following (the decisive element is "tds version").

```
[global]
    port = 1433
    connect timeout = 10
    timeout = 10
    tds version = 8.0
    text size = 64512
```

The problem is, adjusting freetds.conf is not an acceptable solution. I need the connection parameters, especially "tds version" and "port", to be specified in the Perl code, like one can do when connecting to any other brand of database. I tried changing the data-source specification as follows, but DBD::Sybase ignores these parameters.

```
"dbi:Sybase:server=mydb.example.com;port=1433;tds_version=8.0;timeout=10"
```

How does one adjust these parameters, other than through freetds.conf?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create an alternative config file and supply it to the DBI through the `interfaces` parameter:

```
$dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:Sybase:interfaces=/path/to/your/config',
                    $user, $passwd);
```

Comment: Huh. That would be sufficient, but that doesn't seem to have any effect either. I'm suspicious that there's a bug in DBD::Sybase, that it's not parsing any parameters besides server=.